# c++ need help to understand

Tags: c++

So I have this piece of code. 
I understand all the things beside the fact that when does the loop actually take place again. I mean what is meant by the e(!valid) statement. Does it refer to its numeric value or what? Can somebody please explain this to me. Consider all required variable declared. And ignore uppercase.
The code is:

```cpp
do
{

    valid=1;
    gotoxy(22,7);
    gets(emailid);
    int flag=0;
    for (int i = 0; emailid[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (emailid[i] == '@')
            flag++;
    If(!flag)
    {
        valid = 0;
        cout << "not a valid id. Try again";
        getch();
    }
} while(!valid);
```

So mainly I want to know that it is working, with emphasis on what does !valid and !fail mean.
From what I could get, it has to do with its numeric values but I am still confused.

Comment: This doesn't even compile. C++ is case sensitive.

Comment: @Dave No we won't "ignore" anything. Post your real code. Who knows what errors your fake post is hiding? Take the 30 seconds involved in writing a proper question with formatting, grammar, capital letters and real code that exists... then maybe we'll take the 5 minutes involved in answering it!

Comment: Also do not tag C++ questions as C; thanks.

Comment: @Dave, please perform a simple search for logic operators in C++, then come back. Thank you.

Comment: Okay. Well, I am using my mobile. So I'll try to post the correct code asap.

Comment: @DaveTad: Even if we were to ignore the uppercase and lowercase, we cannot tell you anything about `!valid` or `! Fail`  because only one of those variables exists, and the other one does not have a visible declaration. We can't just "consider it declared". What type does it have? Come on!

Comment: @DaveTad Help with what? I don't even get what you're asking about.

Comment: Then I suggest deleting the question until you are in a position to pose it properly. Wait until you're _not_ on mobile.

Comment: @DaveTad see [Logical operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) for the meaining of `!`

Comment: Well , its a movie hall ticket managing project. So its 1500 lines of coding or mpre which I certainly cannot copy paste.

Comment: Tried to make the code more readable with an edit...

Comment: @DaveTad: Nobody wants 1,500 lines. We want you to post the 10-15 line _minimal testcase_ that you should already have been debugging with. Just a `main` function and actual declarations for the variables you're asking about would do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question:

```
} while (!valid);
```

means: treat the integer behind `valid` as a boolean.  (assuming it is an integer, as it was given a value of 1)

```
i == 0 -> false
i != 0 -> true
```

!valid:

```
valid == 0 -> true
valid != 0 -> false
```

Comment: Yes let's promote underspecified questions by answering them, good idea

Comment: Well - if the real question is obvious (like the last two lines in the question were), and the pasted code shows it can be answered - then why not?

Answer (score 2):

In C++ the value 0 is considered "false" and any other integer is considered "true". In this case while valid is equal to 0 the loop runs.

Answer (score 2):

Numeric value can be promoted to `bool` type this way:
Zero means `false` and other values mean `true`. So `!valid` will return true only if `valid == 0`.
What it means is your `do while()` loop will repeat itself until `valid` equals value other than `0`.